# PHP replace link in tags like [LINK]

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, I want to make it so that if a user types:

`[LINK] url [/LINK]`

It will replace it with the anchor tag:

`<a href=url>url</a>`

How would I show this? I'm not sure how to translate this into regex...

I've tried the following:

`[LINK][a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+[/LINK]`

But obviously that isn't right :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '[LINK]http://google.com[/LINK]';
$str = preg_replace('/\[link\]([^\[\]]+)\[\/link\]/i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str);

echo $str; // <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
```

Explanation:

```
\[link\]    Match "[LINK]"
([^\[\]]+)  Match any character except "[" and "]"
\[\/link\]  Match "[/LINK]"
i           Make it case-insensitive
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone This solves the string replacement problem. *Checking valid URLs* should be asked in another question.

Answer (score 0):

Catch links but would always require leading **http://** or **https://** else the url would be *example.com/google.com* also you should use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) as its possible to xss unsanitized input.

**Here are some examples:**

```
<?php
//The callback function to pass matches as to protect from xss.
function xss_protect($value){
    if(isset($value[2])){
        return '<a rel="nofollow" href="'.htmlentities($value[1]).'">'.htmlentities($value[2]).'</a>';
    }else{
        return '<a rel="nofollow" href="'.htmlentities($value[1]).'">'.htmlentities($value[1]).'</a>';
    }
}


$link ='[LINK]http://google.com[/LINK]';
$link = preg_replace_callback("/\[LINK\](.*)\[\/LINK\]/Usi", "xss_protect", $link);
echo $link;
?>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://google.com">google.com</a>
```

Or Strip the http:// & https:// from the link then append it when outputting.

```
<?php
$link ='[LINK]google.com[/LINK]';
$link = preg_replace_callback("/\[LINK\](.*)\[\/LINK\]/Usi", "xss_protect", str_replace(array('http://','https://'),'',$link));
echo $link;
?>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://google.com">google.com</a>
```

Or A different way to have BB code links, then you can specify Link name from link address, the call back function can be made to handle multiple types of outputs.

```
<?php
$link ='[LINK=google.com]Google[/LINK]';
$link = preg_replace("/\[LINK=(.*)\](.*)\[\/LINK\]/Usi", "xss_protect", str_replace(array('http://','https://'),'',$link));
echo $link;
?>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```